# Delete whitespace before and after word

Tags: whitespace, plugin-vim-surround

I have some text with two dashes:

```
This is some text -- with two dashes.
```

I want to delete the space before and after the dashes:

```
This is some text--with two dashes.
```

Is there a way this can be done without simply pressing `x` on each space?

I thought maybe vim-surround works with spaces, so I tried `ds<Space>`, but it didn't work.

Comment: There's not really an idiomatic shortcut for this. You could make a mapping or something, or custom operator for this, but I doubt it would end up much shorter than `XElx` or `Xf x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a substitution:

```
:%s/ \+-- \+/--/gc
```

With `g` flag to be executed globally on the lines (not only first occurrence per line) and `c` to confirm (to make sure it does not change things you did not want)

Answer (score 3):

### vim-surround by tpope on [github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)

I have tried following undocumented feature of vim-surround

```
ds<space><space>
```

and it worked for me.

This has been added in commit [Support `ds<space><space>`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/commit/e38dea39723c49caa7700f1b8904314e07a82a65) (7 Aug 2015
).
This commit was added after the release of version `2.1` (2015-02-08) which is currently the newest version on [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697). Therefore, this feature is only available if you have pulled in a newer version from [github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). Most plugin manager, e.g. vim-plug or minpac, do this anyway.

BTW, there is an alternative plugin [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) which supports this as well (here by default `sd<space>`).